# Blazor: System.InvalidOperationException: Unable to resolve service for type 'DbContext' while attempting to activate FluentValidator

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, entity-framework-core, blazor-webassembly, fluentvalidation

I'm trying to implement validation for Forms in Blazor WebAssembly. I've decided to use FluentValidation with Blazored.FluentValidation package, but I encountered a problem with validators that use DbContext, for example, to check if there is no other person in db with the given email, phoneNr, or personal ID.

[Full Exception message](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UXRCx.png)

EmployeeValidator.cs

```cs
public class EmployeeValidator : AbstractValidator<EmployeeDto>
    {
        public EmployeeValidator(GymDbContext dbContext)
        {
            RuleFor(x => x.FirstName)
                .NotEmpty().WithMessage("Imię jest wymagane")
                .Length(2, 20).WithMessage("Imię musi zawierać od 2 do 20 znaków");

            RuleFor(x => x.LastName)
                .NotEmpty().WithMessage("Nazwisko jest wymagane")
                .Length(2, 20).WithMessage("Nazwisko musi zawierać od 2 do 20 znaków");

            RuleFor(x => x.PhoneNr)
                .NotEmpty().WithMessage("Numer telefonu jest wymagany")
                .Length(9, 9).WithMessage("Numer telefonu musi zawierać 9 cyfr")
                .Matches("^[0-9]*$").WithMessage("Numer telefonu może zawierać tylko cyfry")
                .Custom((value, context) =>
                {
                    var phoneNrInUse = dbContext.Person.Any(s => s.PhoneNr == value);
                    if (phoneNrInUse)
                    {
                        context.AddFailure("PhoneNr", "Podany Numer Telefonu jest w użyciu");
                    }
                });

            RuleFor(x => x.Email)
                .NotEmpty().WithMessage("Email jest wymagany")
                .EmailAddress().WithMessage("Email ma niepoprawny format")
                .Custom((value, context) =>
                {
                    var emailInUse = dbContext.Person.Any(s => s.Email == value);
                    if (emailInUse)
                    {
                        context.AddFailure("Email", "Podany Email jest w użyciu");
                    }
                });

            RuleFor(x => x.Pesel)
                .NotEmpty().WithMessage("Pesel jest wymagany")
                .Length(11, 11).WithMessage("Pesel musi zawierać 11 cyfr")
                .Matches("^[0-9]*$").WithMessage("Pesel może zawierać tylko cyfry")
                .Custom((value, context) =>
                {
                    var peselInDb = dbContext.Person.Any(s => s.Pesel == value);
                    if (peselInDb)
                    {
                        context.AddFailure("Pesel", "Podany pesel jest w użyciu");
                    }
                });

            RuleFor(x => x.Password)
                .NotEmpty().WithMessage("Hasło jest wymagane");

            RuleFor(x => x.ConfirmPassword)
                .Equal(x => x.Password).WithMessage("Hasło i potwierdzenie hasła są różne");

            RuleFor(x => x.Salary)
                .NotEmpty().WithMessage("Wynagrodzenie jest wymagane")
                .GreaterThan(0).WithMessage("Wynagrodzenie musi być liczbą dodatnią");
        }
    }
```

EmployeeForm.razor

```
@page "/employeeAdd"
@page "/employeeForm/{FormMode}/{CurrentID}"
@using Projekt_Inzynierski.Core.DTOs;
@inject NavigationManager NavigationManager
@inject HttpClient _httpClient

<h3>Dane Pracownika</h3>
<hr />
<EditForm Model="@employeeDto" OnValidSubmit=@OnValidSubmit>
    <FluentValidationValidator />
    <div class="form-group" hidden>
        <input for="Id" class="form-control" @bind="@employeeDto.Id" />
    </div>
    <div class="form-group col-md-3">
        <label for="Email" class="col-form-label">Email:</label>
        <InputText @bind-Value="@employeeDto.Email" class="form-control" disabled="@isDisabled"></InputText>
        <ValidationMessage For="@(() => employeeDto.Email)" />
    </div>
    <div class="form-group col-md-3">
        <label for="Password" class="col-form-label">Hasło:</label>
        <InputText @bind-Value="@employeeDto.Password" class="form-control" type="password" disabled="@isDisabled"></InputText>
        <ValidationMessage For="@(() => employeeDto.Password)" />
    </div>
    <div class="form-group col-md-3">
        <label for="ConfirmPassword" class="col-form-label">Potwierdzenie hasła:</label>
        <InputText @bind-Value="@employeeDto.ConfirmPassword" class="form-control" type="password" disabled="@isDisabled"></InputText>
        <ValidationMessage For="@(() => employeeDto.ConfirmPassword)" />
    </div>  
    <div class="form-group col-md-3">
        <label for="FirstName" class="col-form-label">Imię:</label>
        <InputText @bind-Value="@employeeDto.FirstName" class="form-control" disabled="@isDisabled"></InputText>
        <ValidationMessage For="@(() => employeeDto.FirstName)" />
    </div>
    <div class="form-group col-md-3">
        <label for="LastName" class="col-form-label">Nazwisko:</label>
        <InputText @bind-Value="@employeeDto.LastName" class="form-control" disabled="@isDisabled"></InputText>
        <ValidationMessage For="@(() => employeeDto.LastName)" />
    </div>
    <div class="form-group col-md-3">
        <label for="PhoneNr" class="col-form-label">Numer tel.:</label>
        <InputText @bind-Value="@employeeDto.PhoneNr" class="form-control" disabled="@isDisabled"></InputText>
        <ValidationMessage For="@(() => employeeDto.PhoneNr)" />
    </div>
    <div class="form-group col-md-3">
        <label for="Pesel" class="col-form-label">Pesel:</label>
        <InputText @bind-Value="@employeeDto.Pesel" class="form-control" disabled="@isDisabled"></InputText>
        <ValidationMessage For="@(() => employeeDto.Pesel)" />
    </div>
    <div class="form-group col-md-3">
        <label for="Sal" class="col-form-label">Wynagrodzenie:</label>
        <InputNumber @bind-Value="@employeeDto.Salary" class="form-control" disabled="@isDisabled"></InputNumber>
        <ValidationMessage For="@(() => employeeDto.Salary)" />
    </div>
    <br />
    <div class="form-group col-md-3 list-group-horizontal-sm">
        <input type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" value=@(FormMode != "edit" ? "Zapisz" : "Aktualizuj") />
        <input type="button" class="btn btn-primary" @onclick=@Cancel value="Anuluj" /> 
    </div>
</EditForm>
@code {
    [Parameter]
    public string CurrentID { get; set; }
    [Parameter]
    public string FormMode { get; set; }

    EmployeeDto employeeDto = new EmployeeDto();
    bool isDisabled;

    protected override async Task OnInitializedAsync()
    {
        if (FormMode == "details")
        {
            isDisabled = true;
        }
        if (FormMode == "edit" || FormMode == "details")
        {
            var fetchedEmployee = await _httpClient.GetFromJsonAsync<EmployeeDto>($"api/employee/{CurrentID}");
            if (fetchedEmployee != null)
            {
                employeeDto = fetchedEmployee;
            }
        }

    }

    protected void OnValidSubmit()
    {
        if (FormMode != "edit")
        {
            CreateEmployee();
        }
        else
        {
            UpdateEmployee();
        }
    }

    protected async void CreateEmployee()
    {
        await _httpClient.PostAsJsonAsync("api/employee", employeeDto);
        NavigationManager.NavigateTo("employeeList");
    }

    protected async void UpdateEmployee()
    {
        await _httpClient.PutAsJsonAsync($"api/employee/{CurrentID}", employeeDto);
        NavigationManager.NavigateTo("employeeList");
    }

    void Cancel()
    {
        NavigationManager.NavigateTo("employeeList");
    }
}
```

Program.cs - registering validators

```cs
//Validation
builder.Services.AddFluentValidationAutoValidation(config =>
{
    config.DisableDataAnnotationsValidation = true;
})
    .AddValidatorsFromAssemblyContaining<EmployeeValidator>();
```

If I remove the Custom Rules from the EmployeeValidator.cs file everything works fine but I need them
I searched the internet for a solution but did not find one. Is there other way to do this?

Comment: How do you inject your EmployeeValidator? Could you share your code about registering the service?

Comment: @QingGuo I've added a fragment of code from Program.cs